# Rebase the protected branch without PR

Tags: git, gitlab, git-rebase

I have `master` and `hotfix_master` branches. These are release branches and are protected in Gitlab UI under project settings.

what I'm trying to achieve is, rebase the `hotfix_master` branch after every production release which happens from `master` so that if customer raises any bug, we can fix that bug on `hotfix_master` branch and release to customer.

while doing a proof of concept, I realized is that even though `hotfix_master` branch is protected, I can still rebase without creating any PR. Is that expected? if yes, what the use of protection? and what should be done to allow rebase only after creating PR?

**EDIT 1**

This is what I am doing

```
    - git fetch
    - git checkout hotfix_master
    - git diff --name-only origin/hotfix_master...origin/master
    - git rebase origin/master
    - git status
    - git push
```

after rebasing , what I see is , all the changes from `master` are now on `hotfix_master`. so, where is the question of PR ? why gitlab is not complaining that you haven't raised PR  . Please suggest

**EDIT 2**

[image]

Comment: `I can still rebase without creating any PR` How do you do that?

Comment: please suggest . see EDIT 1

Comment: What is there to suggest? What suggestion do you need? `where is the question of PR ?` There is no "pull request", you did no make any. `why gitlab is not complaining that you haven't raised PR` Why should it? You are only connecting with `git fetch`, you can turn your network connection off after it.

Comment: sorry, forgot to add git push command at the end in EDIT 1.  So my doubt is , I'm able to push the code to hotfix_master branch without PR. Not getting why ?

Comment: And now that changes quite everything ;) . So, well,  what were the exact outputs of each and every command? If you were able to push, it means that there were no change or that you made a typo - in the branch name, wrong project, wrong gitlab server, you did not apply the protection properly, etc. It should have been rejected.

Comment: please see the EDIT 2 : the branches are protected . not sure which setting is missing

Comment: ? Developers+maintainers are alllowed to push and to merge. You are not allowed to push __--force__, not any push. If you do not want to be allowed to push, then remove it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

["Branch protection"](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/protected_branches.html) is a feature of GitLab and GitHub. It protects branches in the shared repository from being force-pushed, potentially losing history.

When you have a local clone, you can do whatever you like to *your local* branches (create them, reset them, merge them, rebase them, create commits, etc.), but you can only perform fast-forward pushes on the "protected branches).

Comment: please suggest . see EDIT 1

Comment: @user2315104 running `git push` after rebasing your local branch will fail if your server settings are correct and the branch is really affected. Everything _before_ pushing is not affected by any branch settings on the server.

Comment: please see the EDIT 2 : the branches are protected . not sure which setting is missing

Comment: @user2315104 again, _local_ operations are _not_ affected by branch settings. Why would they? `git push` for non-fast-forward on these branches is prevented. GitLab is completely unaware of anything happening in your local clone until you push. Only the push can fail

Comment: ok. got it . thanks

Answer (score 0):

In this setup, if hotfix_master has commits that master does not have, the push (last command in **EDIT 1**) should fail because of branch protection.

If you want the normal push (which does not allow altering history) to be denied, you have to change the protection settings (**Edit 2**) "Allowed to push" to a higher level, denying it to anyone who should not do what you demonstrated in **Edit 1**.

Beside that: Assuming master is the code that is currently in production, you'd usually merge master to other branches to preserve the commit history between branches.